# How change keyboard navigation with down and next arrow key?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I would like to change the behaviour of the down key in my FancyBox without changing the one of next key.

Right > next image

Down > third image (means "next" x 2)

Is it possible ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may need to re-assign the *arrow keys* behavior by using the API option `keys` like :

```
keys: {
    next: {
        13: "left", // enter
        34: "up", // page down
        39: "left", // right arrow
        // 40: "up" // disable down key
    },
    prev: {
        8: "right", // backspace
        33: "down", // page up
        37: "right", // left arrow
        38: "down" // up arrow
    },
    close: [27], // escape key
    play: [32], // space - start/stop slideshow
    toggle: [70] // letter "f" - toggle fullscreen
}
```

**Notice** we commented out the down-key (`40`) in the API option

```
// 40: "up" // disable down key
```

... so fancybox won't bind any *event* to it.

Then, we can *bind* the `keydown` *event* to the down-arrow within the `beforeShow` fancybox callback (and we can turn it off after closing fancybox) to advance **2** positions from the **current** element of the gallery. We will use the fancybox `$.fancybox.jumpto()` method but passing the current parameters instead of a hard-coded *index* value like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        keys: {
            next: {
                13: "left", // enter
                34: "up", // page down
                39: "left", // right arrow
                // 40: "up" // disable down key
            },
            prev: {
                8: "right", // backspace
                33: "down", // page up
                37: "right", // left arrow
                38: "down" // up arrow
            },
            close: [27], // escape key
            play: [32], // space - start/stop slideshow
            toggle: [70] // letter "f" - toggle fullscreen
        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
                if (code == 40) {
                    // advance to the third image from the current
                    $.fancybox.jumpto($.fancybox.current.index + 2)
                }
            });
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            // unbind the keydown event
            $(document).off("keydown")
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

Answer (score 0):

You can add this functionality manually by hooking into the FancyBox public methods:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {  
    switch(e.keyCode)
    {
        // The down arrow == 40:
        case 40:
            $.fancybox.jumpto(2);
            break;
    }
});
```

The `fancybox.jumpto()` function will display the item at the specified index (in this case, the third item). You can learn more about the public methods of FancyBox [**here**](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs).

Comment: I guess the OP wants to move to the third image from the **current** image while navigating through the gallery, which is "next" x 2. `$.fancybox.jumpto(2)` won't do that but jump to the third image of the whole gallery regardless from where you pressed the down key.

Answer (score 0):

I need to admit this might be a quite general jQuery answer, but for anyone interested in an alternative approach, here's the code :

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if ($(".fancybox").length == 0) return;/* check if element exists; */
    if (e.keyCode == 40){                  /* 40 = down key */
        e.preventDefault();
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");   /* get a template event object */
        e.which = 39;                      /* Change it to "right key" */ 
        $(document).keydown(e);            /* Trigger the event two times */
        $(document).keydown(e);
    }
});
```

One should note that using the `length` property requires the complete removal of the element(s) out of the `DOM` if one wants to stop the functionality. Another approach could be using `$(".fancybox")` as selector; however, this would require that the element exists before above code runs.

Comment: This will always call the next image * 2. It will not explicitly set the third image...

Comment: I think we interpret his question differently; I think `right = next` , and that he needs `down` to be `2x next`, thus `2x right`.

Comment: @BenM : agree with Tacticus. I think you misread the question

Comment: @Tacticus : the potential issue to binding `keydown` to the `document` is it will trigger an error if fancybox is closed.